# Add an existing VM in Autoscaling Sclae Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling

Is it possible to add an existing Virtual Machine (already spawned one) in an Azure Autoscaling scale set (which is going to be spawned)? Is there any ARM template which is available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a syspreped VHD image of your VM, it is possible to use it:

> Q. How do you create a VM scale set using a custom image?
>
> A. Leave the vhdContainers property blank, for example:
>
> ```
> "storageProfile": {
>     "osDisk": {
>         "name": "vmssosdisk",
>         "caching": "ReadOnly",
>         "createOption": "FromImage",
>         "image": {
>             "uri": "https://mycustomimage.blob.core.windows.net/system/Microsoft.Compute/Images/mytemplates/template-osDisk.vhd"
>         },
>         "osType": "Windows"
>     }
> },
> ```

Source : [Virtual Machine Scale Sets Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview/)

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful :)